# Compiling GLIB with external PCRE

Tags: visual-studio, glib

I wish to compile the GLIB using Visual Studio Solution file included
in its source.
However, I have already compiled PCRE and have it ready in the computer.

[This article](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GTK+/Win32/MSVCCompilationOfGTKStack) talks about including PCRE external to the source by using
a suffix _ExtPCRE.

But I don't have an idea how to accomplish this. Moreover I didn't really
understand whether this suffix is a compilar/linker flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought of deleting this question as I already found the answer but then thought it might be useful for somebody else.

What I was looking was the "project context". You can change it in the
configurations manager, steps as follows

- Right click the project and go to properties.
- On the properties window click on the "Configuration Manager" at the top right.
- Click on the Configuration dropdown and select the appropriate one.

[image]

Comment: I would like to know if we could change this using a config file that ships with the source.

Comment: On a related note, possible plans upstream has for bundled pcre - https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=755693

Comment: @TingPing: Thank you for this. This indeed justifies my decision to go ahead with external pcre which is the latest one. In fact i guessed that the one that ships with glib will be old. :)